# mySQL error when deleting from table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having an issue with mySQL in my PHP every time I try and delete an entry in my table it deletes but outputs an error. The errors are as follows:

> Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Couldn't fetch mysqli
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given
>
> Warning: mysqli_close() [function.mysqli-close]: Couldn't fetch mysqli

I can't seem to work out why this is happening, it may be quite simple but I am rather new to the mySQL so hopefully someone more advanced can show me where I'm going wrong.

```
<?
if(isset($_GET['deleteTweet'])) {
    $deleteTweet = $_GET['deleteTweet'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM bestTweets WHERE id=".$deleteTweet;

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Record deleted successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}

$sql = "SELECT id, tName, tUsername, tTimeDate, tBody FROM bestTweets";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$onMouseOver = 'onmouseover="this.src='."'IMAGES/binBtn_Hover.svg'".'" ';
$onMouseOut = 'onmouseout="this.src='."'IMAGES/binBtn.svg'".'"';

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo 
        '<div id="tweetContainer" class="tweetContainer">
            <div id="tweetMain">
                <div id="tweetName">
                    <p>'.$row['tName'].'</p>
                </div>'.

                '<div id="tweetUsername">
                    <p>'.$row['tUsername'].'</p>
                </div>'.

                '<div id="tweetDateTime">
                    <p>' .$row['tTimeDate'].'</p>
                </div>'.

                '<div id="tweetBody">
                    <p>'.$row["tBody"].'</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tweetSave">
                    <form action="Saved.php?isset=true&deleteTweet='.$row["id"].'" method="post">
                        <button type="submit"  name="binBtn1" class="saveBtn"><img src="IMAGES/binBtn.svg"'.$onMouseOver.$onMouseOut.' width="50px" height="50px"></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';}
    }
    else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Have you defined `$conn` as the connection? And why do you `mysqli_close($conn);` before you are done with querying?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and you should use mysqli with [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score 2):

If your deleting a row, the last thing you do is close the connection!

Change to...

```
<?
if(isset($_GET['deleteTweet'])) {
    $deleteTweet = $_GET['deleteTweet'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM bestTweets WHERE id=".$deleteTweet;

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Record deleted successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    //mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

The next query was trying to use a closed connection.

Comment: In addition, he should check if `$conn` is a mysqli connection or not. IIRC `mysqli_open(...)` returns `NULL` if opening the connection failed.

Comment: I am making a lot of assumptions - the connection works for the delete and therefore is OK and that OP will at some point change to using prepared statements.  But for now this should at least show where the problem is.

Comment: Indeed, there is room for improvement but your answer points to the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Check that you have successfully established the connection (as I can not find `$con` in your code).
2. Ensure that you have not prematurely closed the connection.